# Django LDAP Authentication in Production

Tags: python, django, ldap

I'm using an LDAP authentication module for logging into my django app. This works fine to log-in but I am having trouble with a function that use's:

```
request.user.is_authenticated():
```

This works fine on my dev machine (also using ldap), but on production will not return the information associated to the user. In particular, I am retrieving a set of events based on the users primary key.

```
eventList = Event.objects.filter(employee_id = request.user.pk)
```

The events exist (they are rendered within another view) and I'm quite sure it is that one statement.  It is worth noting that although I've sub-classed User as follows, but the employees are created (I've checked in the admin interface):

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    # This field is required.
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    manager_id = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name = 'employees', null = True)

    def __unicode__(self):
     return self.user.username

def create_user_profile(sender, **kwargs):
    """When creating a new user, make an employee profile too."""
    u = kwargs["instance"]
    if not Employee.objects.filter(user = u):
        Employee(user=u).save()

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender = User)
```

Could anyone help?

Comment: What error messages are you getting?

Comment: Actually, now you mention it, the template is returned but it is empty. So, I assume that means the issue is with the query?

Comment: I don't think you need to recast the query as a list, it should already be a list that gets returned from the Django ORM. Try to remove that and see what happens?

Comment: You're right, the casting is not necessary but that doesn't resolve my issue.

Comment: Hmmm, I would directly stick in some of the things you are querying on, like request.user.pk into the template. So just do things like {{request.user.pk}} in the html, and see what they are. That and try some things in the shell, make sure that the query returns something when you do Employee.objects.filter(employee_id = 10)

Answer (score 0):

This was down to my query. Basically, the original query was assuming that each Employee and User object has the same PK. This was OK in development, but didn't work in production as the keys didn't match.

Replacing the original query with the one below resolved things:

```
    employee = request.user.employee
    eventList = Event.objects.filter(employee_id = employee.pk)
```